# Domain Driven Design Map database object to domain model

Tags: domain-driven-design

I everyone, i am trying to implements hexagonale architecture with DDD in java with the Quarkus framework.
I have some questions about how i can copy my jpa entity into my domain.

Here is a simple use case :
I have a java class :

```java
public class Container {

    private UUID id;
    private String name;
    private Set<Container> containers = new HashSet<>();
    private Container parent;
    private AnotherObject anotherObject;

    
    public void addContainer(Container container) {
        container.setParent(this);
        this.containers.add(container);

        this.updateAnotherObject()
    }
}
```

So, as soon as i add a child container to a parent, i need to update "anotherObject". This works fine when i start from nothing, create my containers and persist them in database by copying all attributes in my JPA model.

The issue is in the opposite way. I through my REST API, the client call the endpoint to add a new child Container. The first thing i do is to request my database to get the parent ContainerEntity. Then i map the ContainerEntity to a Container (my domain).
But when i map ContainerEntity to Container, i call the method "addContainer" and the method "addContainer" will also call the "updateAnotherObject" which will trigger some computation that i do not need, because i also have the value of "anotherObject" in my database, so i would just need to set copy it to my domain.

How can i handle this case, without having to create some public setters which will break the DDD because everyone could ask the setter directly and skip domain verification.

Any ideas ?
Thanks